# How can I disable 'Data Analysis in Real Time component' in windows 2012 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

I am running windows 2012 server R2. I see this process 'Data Analysis in Real Time component' takes up a lot of my CPU.  I have tried

- go 'System Center Endpoint Protection' and disable 'Real-time protection' and then restart my PC.
- manually 'End task' for 'System Center Endpoint Protection' in Task Manager.

But I am still seeing the issue.  Can you please tell me how can I disable this 'Data Analysis in Real Time component'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gathered, the System Center Endpoint Protection you are referring to is the pre-installed malware/antivirus solution for Windows provided as a Windows service.

[image]

The service itself has been hardened, making it pretty much [impossible to stop](https://www.windows-noob.com/forums/topic/7593-temporarily-disable-endpoint-protection/). This is probably made to prevent personnel from the client side from tampering with the process.

---

There is, however, an [article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mspfe/2013/02/19/anti-tampering-for-the-antimalware-service-in-system-center-endpoint-protection-2012-sp1/) detailing how to troubleshoot and diagnose the service in the event of performance degradation, as per your case.

- Verify Proper Exclusions are set by Product.  Windows exclusion lists
  can be found here:  Windows Anti-Virus Exclusion List
- Verify the process is excluded in Real Time Protection.
- For VDI, verify a Full Scan has been run on the Master Host Image, and that persistent cache has been populated.

  - You can check the value in    `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft

    Antimalware\Scan\SFCState` – if it’s 7 then it’s complete, on initial
    install it will be 0
  - To force the persistent cache to generate, run (from an elevated    CMD):

    `cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client`

    `MpCmdRun.exe -buildSFC)`

Test Disabling the following Endpoint Protection Components “one at a time” to see if the issue can be isolated to a specific component:

- Disable Network Inspection System (NIS)
- Disable Behavior Monitoring
- Disable Real Time Protection

Tools to assist during Troubleshooting:

- Use Taskman (listed Above)
- Use Event Viewer
- Use Process Explorer
- Use Process Monitor

---

If you prefer not to mess with SCEP and simply have it removed all together, you can create a package/program to [uninstall](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/988ba957-d18a-4330-a6d1-39505a86226b/i-have-to-uninstall-end-point-protection-from-all-of-my-computers-in-domain-through-system-center?forum=configmanagerdeployment) it and have it execute the following command.

```
C:\Windows\ccmsetup\scepinstall.exe /u /s
```

Where `/u = uninstall` and `/s = client`. This will remove all preexisting installation of SCEP on client machines as well.